# how do i read a csvfile faster in c++

Tags: c++

This is my current code:

```
    std::vector <OrderBookEntry> entries;
    std::ifstream csvFile{ csvFilename };
    std::string line;

    if (csvFile.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(csvFile, line)) {
            try {
                std::stringstream ss(line);
                OrderBookEntry obe = stringsToOBE(tokenise(line, ','));
                entries.push_back(obe);
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV bad data" << std::endl;

            }

        }//end of while loop

        
    }
    
    std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV read " << entries.size() << " entries" << std::endl;
    return entries;

}
```

```
OrderBookEntry::OrderBookEntry(double _price,
    double _amount,
    std::string _timestamp,
    std::string _product,
    OrderBookType _orderType,
    std::string _username)

    : price(_price),
    amount(_amount),
    timestamp(_timestamp),
    product(_product),
    orderType(_orderType),
    username(_username)

{

}
```

example of csv file:
[image: csv file]

Hi all, I have a csvfile (1 mill+) rows and i am trying to read and store the entries faster. Currently it takes a bit of time before my program is able to read the data and run.
How do i read the csvFile quicker? Thanks!

Comment: What is `tokenise`? What is `stringstoOBE`?  Are you running a debug, unoptimized build, or a build with optimizations turned on when you built the application?  Any code that concerns the spped of a C++ application must also state the compiler and compiler options used to build the application.  If you are running a debug or unoptimized build, then the timings you are seeing are meaningless.

Comment: ```tokenise``` is just a function which breaks the string up into "tokens". ```stringstoOBE``` is another function which takes in a vector of these "tokens" and labels them into the different data types.

Comment: And what if those functions are causing the probable slowness?  Wouldn't it make sense to post them?  Better yet, post a [mcve].

Comment: @TanJunRong What you should do is *profile* your code to find out what is taking the time. Then you can focus your efforts there, instead of guessing what is taking the most time. Every quality compiler comes with a profiling tool, so find out about the one that works with your compiler.

Comment: Show the definition of `OrderBookEntry`. In fact, do as @PaulMcKenzie suggests and put a [mre] in the question

Comment: There are some simple 'no cost' optimizations you can make, for instance `entries.push_back(obe);` -> `entries.push_back(std::move(obe));` Then add a *move constructor* for your `OrderBookEntry` class.

Comment: @TanJunRong -- Do the obvious thing first.  Remove everything in the `while` loop and read the entire file but do nothing.  Is the file reading still slow?  If it isn't, then it has nothing to do with reading the file -- it has everything to do with what you are doing within the `while` loop.  As a matter of fact, if you had no idea of what a profiler does, this is what you should have done to identify which lines may be causing the issue.  You should have removed lines from the code to see which one or which combination of lines are truly causing the slowness.

Comment: `getline` and then putting it into a `stringstream` that you parse is convenient, but it's not fast. It'd be faster to parse `csvFile` directly into the fields of the `OrderBookEntry`

Comment: @TanJunRong `int linecount = 0; while (std::getline(csvFile, line)) { ++linecount; } std::cout << linecount;` -- How long does that take?  Again, if this is fast, then it isn't the reading of the lines in the file that is the issue.

Comment: hi i added a ```cout``` and could see how the program was reading the data line by line but it takes awhile to read finish as there 1 mill+ rows. So i think the issue here would be in my while loop where its returns ```entries```

Comment: @TanJunRong Why don't you add enough code so that we can help you? Show the definition of `OrderBookEntry` and also an example of a line in the file.

Comment: @TanJunRong Do not add `cout` in the middle of the `while` loop, as what you are doing is adding the time it takes the output to reach the console a million times.  Do as my previous comment does -- increment a counter *and that's it* -- nothing else.

Comment: When optimizing code ALWAYS MEASURE, find your bottlenecks using a profiler. But in this case if you really have a speed problem then you should change from a CSV file to a binary file format (and they will have their own issues). CSV files are just slow to read (as most human readable file formats) because they need parsing.

Comment: I have seen this before on codereview. Apparently a homework assignment. Though, it was a while ago.

Comment: actually, how do i read more than one line at a time? because right now my code is reading line by line.

Comment: @TanJunRong Why are you still not showing us the definition of `OrderBookEntry` and an example of a few of the lines in the csv file? It's like you actually don't want help

Comment: hey my bad, i just added updated it!

Comment: the problem is the function only returns ```entries``` AFTER it is done reading and tokenising the 1 million data, which is maybe why it takes awhile to load up the program.

Comment: 1) A picture of the data won't help us. Post it as text. 2) You still haven't shown the definition of `OrderBookEntry`, only a constructor.  3) The data in the csv file doesn't seem to match the fields in that constructor. I looked at your history of questions and you haven't gotten many answers and you haven't accepted a single one of those few answers that you've gotten. It seems really hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer.

Please see below a solution that can create a test file with 1 million records.

I then make only the input buffer bigger, without any further optimization.

Then, all lines of the test file are read and parsed in 2.6seconds.

The question is now: Is this fast or is this slow? Please comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

const std::array<std::string, 3> OTString{ "bid","offer","trade" };

enum class OrderType : int { bid, offer, trade, invalid };
const std::unordered_map<std::string, OrderType> OrderTypeMap{ {OTString[0],OrderType::bid}, {OTString[1],OrderType::offer}, {OTString[2],OrderType::trade} };
OrderType getOrderType(std::string& ot) {
    if (const auto it = OrderTypeMap.find(ot); it != OrderTypeMap.cend())
        return it->second;
    else
        return OrderType::invalid;
}

const std::string testFileName{ "test.txt" };

void createTestFile() {
    unsigned ms{};
    unsigned second{};
    unsigned minute{};
    std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis1(0.01, 1);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis2(1.0, 1000.0);


    std::string product{"AAAAAAAAAAAA"};

    if (std::ofstream ofs{ testFileName }; ofs) {

        ofs << std::setfill('0') << std::right;
        for (std::size_t row{}; row < 1'000'000; ++row) {

            ofs << std::setw(2) << minute << ':' << std::setw(2) << second << ':' << ms << ','
                << product << ',' << OTString[row%3] << ',' << dis1(gen) << ',' << dis2(gen) << '\n';


            ++product[product.length() - 1];
            for (std::size_t i{ product.length() - 1 }; i > 0; --i)
                if (product[i] > 'Z') {
                    product[i] = 'A';
                    ++product[i - 1];
                }
                else
                    break;
            if (row % 100 == 0) {
                ++ms;
                if (ms > 9) {
                    ms = 0;
                    ++second;
                    if (second > 59) {
                        second = 0;
                        ++minute;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for writing.\n\n";
}
// For measuring durations
struct Timer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTime{};
    long long elapsedTime{};
    void start() { startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
    void stop() { elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) { return os << t.elapsedTime << " ms "; }
};
constexpr std::size_t IOBufSize = 5'000'000;
char ioBuf[IOBufSize];

struct OrderBookEntry {
    std::string timestamp{};
    std::string product{};
    OrderType orderType{};
    double amount{};
    double price{};
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, OrderBookEntry& obe) {
        std::string ot{}; char c;
        std::getline(is >> std::ws, obe.timestamp, ',');
        std::getline(is >> std::ws, obe.product, ',');
        std::getline(is >> std::ws, ot, ',');
        is >> obe.amount >> c >> obe.price;
        obe.orderType = getOrderType(ot);
        return is;
    }
};

int main() {
    //createTestFile();

    std::vector<OrderBookEntry> obe{};
    obe.reserve(1'500'000);

    if (std::ifstream ifs{ testFileName }; ifs) {

        // To speed up reading of the file, we will set a bigger input buffer
        ifs.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ioBuf, IOBufSize);

        Timer t; t.start();

        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<OrderBookEntry>(ifs), {}, std::back_inserter(obe));
        std::cout << "\nRecords read: "<< obe.size() << '\n';

        t.stop();
        std::cout << t << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for reading.\n\n";
}
```